# Unable to get my Google Ads to be responsive

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, adsense

Really not sure where I am going wrong here but I am using Boostrap and my understanding is that Google Ads can be responsive in accordance with the parent size.

So, here is my code (and I have correctly selected 'responsive' ads from AdSense) but no joy...

Any idea what I am doing wrong? PS This code comes directly from google here: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/6307124

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12">


              <script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js"></script>
              <!-- IC Throughtout Site -->
              <ins class="adsbygoogle example_responsive_1"
                   style="display:block"
                   data-ad-client="ca-pub-XXX"
                   data-ad-slot="XXX"
                   data-ad-format="horizontal"></ins>
              <script>
              (adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
              </script>



          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

The CSS is here:

```
<style>
.example_responsive_1 { width: 320px; height: 100px; }
@media(min-width: 500px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 468px; height: 60px; } }
@media(min-width: 800px) { .example_responsive_1 { width: 728px; height: 90px; } }
</style>
```

If I resize it the ad stays the same size...odd....